# unable to start the bundle created using maven archetype in apache karaf

Tags: maven, osgi, osgi-bundle, karaf

I tried to create an osgi bundle using apache karaf using maven archetype as mentioned in the karaf devlopers guide  .

`mvn archetype:generate \-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.karaf.archetypes \-DarchetypeArtifactId=karaf-bundle-archetype \-DarchetypeVersion=4.0.0 \-DgroupId=com.mycompany \-DartifactId=TestBundle \-Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT \-Dpackage=com.mycompany.newpkg`

so i have a directory created TestBundle  and then i did "mvn install" here . So the bundle (jar file) is created in the target folder . when i copy this folder on deploy , i see that it is installed , but on restarting i see this issue below

```
karaf@victoria>bundle:list | grep Test
396 | Installed   |  80 | 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT               | TestBundle Bundle
karaf@victoria>bundle:info 396

TestBundle Bundle (396)
-----------------------
karaf@victoria>bundle:restart 396
Error executing command: Error restarting bundles:
Unable to start bundle 396: The bundle "TestBundle_1.0.0.SNAPSHOT [396]"
    could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint:
        Import-Package: org.osgi.framework; version="[1.8.0,2.0.0)"
```

My pom.xml import-package has nothing but a star.
    
    *

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1446200540685
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_51
Bundle-Activator: com.mycompany.newpkg.Activator
Bundle-Description: TestBundle OSGi bundle project.
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: TestBundle Bundle
Bundle-SymbolicName: TestBundle
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: com.mycompany.newpkg;version="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT";uses:="org
 .osgi.framework"
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="[1.8,2)"
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5))"
Tool: Bnd-2.4.1.201501161923
```

Comment: Can you please add a link to the „_karaf devlopers guide_“ you're referring to. Can you please add the content of your bundle's `MANIFEST.MF` to the question. Regarding the POMs [`<Import-Package>`](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#import-package): „_This header rarely has to be explicitly specified._“

Comment: [link](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/developers-guide/archetypes.html) - here is where i found maven archetype.

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1446200540685
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_51
Bundle-Activator: com.mycompany.newpkg.Activator
Bundle-Description: TestBundle OSGi bundle project.
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: TestBundle Bundle
Bundle-SymbolicName: TestBundle
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: com.mycompany.newpkg;version="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT";uses:="org
 .osgi.framework"
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="[1.8,2)"
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5))"
Tool: Bnd-2.4.1.201501161923

Comment: Have you realized that formatting is limited in comments? That's why I wrote „_please add the content ... to the question_“. See the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33434630/edit) link below your question's tags.

Comment: Sorry about that . Added the content to the question .

Comment: how about asking at the users mailinglist of the karaf project ... it's still the resource to use for such question, even though spring removed that other projects still have a vibrant community that takes care

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manifest says the bundle was compiled against (and expects at runtime) an OSGi Core R6 Framework (framework version 1.8). Does the version of Karaf you are using support OSGi Core R6?

Comment: But how and where can i find whether the karaf supports OSGi Core R6 ?

Comment: Yes Hargrave , you were right , changing the OSGi Version in pom.xml helped . Thanks ! :)